# Error in GNU parallel dynamic string replacement

Tags: gnu-parallel

I have more than 50 file pairs with names in the following format: AA-7R-76L1.clean.R1.fastq.gz, AA-7R-76L1.clean.R2.fastq.gz

I tried to use parallel in the following way:

```
parallel --plus echo {%R..fastq.gz} ::: *.fastq.gz |parallel 'repair.sh in1={}.R1.fastq.gz in2={}.R2.fastq.gz out1={}.repd.R1.fastq.gz out2={}.repd.R2.fastq.gz outs={}.singletons.fastq.gz repair'
```

`--plus echo` should dynamically replace `R1.fastq.gz, R2.fastq.gz` to capture the sample name i.e.`HB-7R-25L0.clean`. It should then feed it to repair.sh

The error I get is, the first section extracts the entire filename and does not capture the sample name. Thus in1 and in2 becomes `AA-7R-76L1.clean.R1.fastq.gz.R1.fastq.gz and AA-7R-76L1.clean.R2.fastq.gz.R2.fastq.gz`

What is the error here?

Comment: Show us the output of `parallel --dr 'repair.sh...`

Comment: Issue sorted out. This was due to 'Version bug'. With the old version 2016, there was error, while the new version 2020 didn't throw any error.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
$ parallel --plus --dry-run  'repair.sh in1={} in2={/R1/R2} out1={/R1/fixed.R1} out2={/R1/fixed.R2} outs={%.R1.fastq.gz}_singletons.fastq repair' ::: *R1.fastq.gz
```

(Assuming R1 and R2 is not part of the *-part of the name).